# Monotouch Dialog RadioElement tint color IOS7

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have DialogViewController, where I have created RadioGroup with element. The issue I am facing is that checkmark near RasioElement is blue default color, but I would like to set it to my own. Unfortunately there is no option for radioelement or radiogroup to set color. Can you please assist with a way how it can be done.